# How to select the parent node only on parsed xml by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have the XML like this

```html
<Response>
  <Title>
    <RequestID>1</RequestID>
  </Title>
  <RequestID>120</RequestID>
</Response>
```

I need to get the RequestID value 120 only.

```js
var xml = "<Response><Title><RequestID>1</RequestID></Title><RequestID>120</RequestID></Response>";
var xmlData = $.parseXML(xml);
var RID = $xmlData.find('RequestID');
//It is returning the data like [1, 120];
```

How can i get the value from the parent node of the RequestID only not nested child node?

Comment: I'm on phone so I can't give you an elaborate answer, but I feel like the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function could be of use here.

Comment: @Rawrplus I tried that one. Its not working for me. Thanks for your effect. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). The child selector only selects the first-level descendants.

```js
var xml = "<Response><Title><RequestID>1</RequestID></Title><RequestID>120</RequestID></Response>";
var xmlData = $.parseXML(xml);
var RID = $(xmlData).find('Response > RequestID').text();
console.log(RID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @cfprabhu replace `.children` with `.find` in your fiddle

Comment: I tried the find but its return the both. https://jsfiddle.net/o7c8v4me/3/

Comment: @cfprabhu you didn't use the child selector in your fiddle

Comment: @cfprabhu copy the code from the example in my answer